# Including a <div> tag in a PHP script?

Tags: php, html, include

So I've written some PHP/SQL code and that side of things works. When the code retrives a new article however, I want it to also create a div called content, for which I have created a CSS class. I was reccomended to do this elsewhere as the following:

```
$mydiv = '<div name="content">';
$mynew = '</div>';

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    //Output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo $mydiv . "<h1>Title: " . $row["title"] . " <br /></h1><h2>Summary: " . $row["summary"] . " <br /></h2><h5>Author: " . $row["author"] . " </div><br />" . $mynew ;
    }
}   else {
    echo "Cannot find content.";
}
?>
```

Dreamweaver seems to think there's no syntax problems, but when I launch the page on my server a new div is not created, and the text/background doesn't change in accordance with the class?

Kind of new here but seems like a great community, any help would be awesome!

Comment: You are closing 2 `div` but opening just one.

Comment: thanks man! But the script isn't working :/ any advice?

Comment: Have you output errors?

Comment: Haha thanks for pointing out! Changed it though and didn't get it working

Comment: Nope. The actual code seems to work fine, it just doesn't want to create a new div

Comment: Did you check the page source? Is it on the page but just not showing?

Comment: you also do not appear to close the h5 tag

Comment: Also not sure why you feel the need to put the div and closing div in a variable

Comment: valiable == variable

Comment: Ah merci. Literally tried everything to get this damn thing going.

Answer (score 0):

You might find it easier while you are still learning, to de complicate the string concatenation, so it is easier to follow.

Also you need to be careful to create well formed HTML i.e. open and close tags in the right order i.e. the `<h5>` tag

Also to remove some of the start and stop in the string literal building, if you wrap an array referenced variable in `{}` you can use it in a double quoted string just like you would a scalar variable like `$title`

And finally, make sure that you can see the message saying there is no data in the result set from the database by adding[temporarily] a big highlight to it.

```
// just a test
echo '<div style="font-size:20px; color:red">Rows to process: = ';
echo $result->num_rows;
echo '</div>';

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    //Output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo '<div name="content">';
            echo "<h1>Title: {$row['title']}<br /></h1>";
            echo "<h2>Summary: {$row['summary']}<br /></h2>";
            echo "<h5>Author: {$row['author']} </h5><br />";
        echo '<div>';
    }
}   else {
    echo '<div style="font-size:20px; color:red">Cannot find content.</div>';
}
```

Comment: hey man, thanks the code itself is much easier than my own. However, it still doesn't create a div :/

Comment: Hhmmmm Ok try adding that extra bit to show what the number of rows returned by the query is

Comment: Do you see the `Cannot find content` message